# multiple model dialog in VB

Tags: asp.net, model, dialog, popup

I have a aspx page. Users can perform an action on that page. but that actions goes through series of other actions. for example- suppose there is JOin Community link on that page. When user clicks He is asked to Login/Register(A) THEN He is asked to fill up a brief profile(B) THEN he is asked to join community as member/admin etc (C). So there are 3 actions. ALL are to be done on popups/model dialogs (user remains on same page). and I want to create separate controls/pages for all of these steps for reusability. 
I dont want to write HTMLS/server side code of all steps-A, B, C on page itself and I want proper interaction of all model dialogs with page so that depending upon his actions I can decide to show him B C or D dialog box anytime. Suppose user fills some invalid information on step B I should be able to show him step B again after all databse checks with a proper error message so that he can continue from same point where he made error.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need the "ASP.NET 2.0 Wizard Control"

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/21/438732.aspx

Comment: I dont think wizard control is the solution as in wizard control steps are predefined, and I can get the response of user action on a step 2 lets say and decide tht I even want to show step 3 or jump him to step 4. what I want is -

I should be able to load these separate controls and get the response on the page after any action on a control and using that reponse I should be able to load some other control. Every control is returning some response to page and then page is loading another control based on that response.